# intellij step over button does not work as expected

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

My problem is that when I click on **step over**, it does not jump over the addChar method, but enters it. Should not the step over button jump over the method but the **step into** button go into it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRp0J.png

Comment: Do you have a break point in addChar? It will only step over if there isn't a break point somewhere inside

Comment: @ktul Yes, it was. Thank you